# Is it safe to use TortoiseSVN's "Set file dates to the last commit time" feature with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, build-process, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN has a feature to set the file dates to the "last commit time."  The default is false.

This would be nice to use for the purpose of robocopy install scripts.  If one developer does a robocopy install of a website, when I update my repository my file change dates aren't the same as his, so if I try to do an install, the dates are all different and robocopy thinks it needs to update every single file.

However, [TortoiseSVN's docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html) provide this warning: (emphasis mine)

> This option tells TortoiseSVN to set
>   the file dates to the last commit time
>   when doing a checkout or an update.
>   Otherwise TortoiseSVN will use the
>   current date. **If you are developing
>   software it is generally best to use
>   the current date because build systems
>   normally look at the date stamps to
>   decide which files need compiling.** If
>   you use “last commit time” and revert
>   to an older file revision, your
>   project may not compile as you expect
>   it to.

Does this warning rightly apply to Visual Studio?  Is it safe to overlook this warning or will I run into problems down the road?

Or alternatively, is there another stupidly simple installing scheme that would work in place of robocopy?  Keep in mind that I don't want to introduce a lot of extra dependencies, so a 3rd party app, an install script I can't store in SVN, or a solution that requires lot of extra developer training would not be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to copy only files that have actually changed, by checking the file contents. I'm not sure if Robocopy has an option for this, but rsync (for Windows, [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650)) does.

Edit: oh, sorry, "not ideal". Well, I'll just leave it in case it helps.